# using pyppeteer in a continuous scraping mode

Tags: python, pyppeteer

Every example and use case uses pyppeteer where browser is opened and close immediately. e.g.
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

```
async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://someurl')
    content = await page.content()
    cookieslist=await page.cookies()
    cookiejar=createCookieJar(cookieslist)
    await browser.close()
 
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

what happen if you want to keep browser open, and continuously **scrape** the data? thats easily done with selenium, but with pyppeteer, it doesnt work without asyncio it seems. the other way to make it work is to save the session and re-open the browser by schedule and **scrape**, but that feels like a very inefficient way. Anyone tried?

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ and __scrape__ not scrapping or scrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) and continuously pump your data into the queue:

```
import asyncio
import traceback

from contextlib import suppress

from pyppeteer import launch

WORKERS = 10
URLS = [
    "http://airbnb.com",
    "http://amazon.co.uk",
    "http://amazon.com",
    "http://bing.com",
    "http://djangoproject.com",
    "http://envato.com",
    "http://facebook.com",
    "http://github.com",
    "http://google.co.uk",
    "http://google.com",
    "http://google.es",
    "http://google.fr",
    "http://heroku.com",
    "http://instagram.com",
    "http://linkedin.com",
    "http://live.com",
    "http://netflix.com",
    "http://rubyonrails.org",
    "http://shopify.com",
    "http://stackoverflow.com",
    "http://trello.com",
    "http://wordpress.com",
    "http://yahoo.com",
    "http://yandex.ru",
    "http://yiiframework.com",
    "http://youtube.com",
]


async def worker(q, browser):
    # One tab per worker
    page = await browser.newPage()

    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        while True:
            url = await q.get()

            try:
                await page.goto(url, {"timeout": 10000})
                html = await page.content()
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
            else:
                print(f"{url}: {len(html)}")
            finally:
                q.task_done()

    await page.close()


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    browser = await launch(headless=True, args=["--no-sandbox"])

    tasks = []

    for _ in range(WORKERS):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(q, browser)))

    for url in URLS:
        await q.put(url)

    await q.join()

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

    await browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: this could work, but i face same issue that you must know everything in advance. for example, top 10 traded stocks of the day is a dynamic list, based on each stock gather their information as it changes throughout the day. meaning i want a long running pyppeteer that stays open throughout the trading day, scrapping every minute. can i leave the queue running?

Comment: This is just a basic example so you can adjust it to your needs. If you won't cancel the tasks, the `q.get()` method will block, waiting until an item is available. Btw check if there is an API available for the site you're using.

Comment: i'll give a shot. no they have no API, i only simplified the use case, they have tons of anti-scraping tech, thats why i couldn't use requests or requests-html properly due to heavy javascript data. i was using selenium but the memory leak is quite serious and most days the selenium process will crash. i hoping to use pyppeteer because its in-process and hoping i can mix the usage with requests.